# Convert video to frames python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert a c.5 minute video into c.600 frames, 2 frames for every second. When I use the code below it appears to spit out a lot more than 600 frames, I hit 13,000 frames before I was able to exit the command.

here is the properties of my mp3 file.
length: 00:05:06
Frame width: 256
Frame height: 144
Data rate: 78kbps
Total bitrate: 204kbps
Frame rate: 30

I have confirmed that `vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)` is in milliseconds so `sec*1000` should make it into seconds.

I checked the Sec values using a print and they are counting up correctly.

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import cv2
import numpy as numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('4K Traffic camera video - Low.mp4')

def getFrame(sec):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('Video_Frame_Low', str(count) + '.jpg'), image)     # save frame as JPG file
    return hasFrames

sec = 0
frameRate = 0.5 #//it will capture image in each 0.5 second
count=1
success = getFrame(sec)

while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
```

code taken from https://medium.com/@iKhushPatel/convert-video-to-images-images-to-video-using-opencv-python-db27a128a481

I expect to get 612 frames

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with my own video file and it appeared to work as expected.

You could try manually setting the FPS:

```
vidcap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30.0)
```

Failing that, try shifting the frames directly and observe the images that it spits out:

```
vidcap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, sec*30.0)
```